# Как загрузить файл в облачное хранилище (Google Drive, Яндекс Диск)?

Tags: java, telegram-bot

В процессе создания телеграмм бота,мне понадобилось загружать файлы, которые отправляют пользователи, в облачное хранилище.Возможно я плохо искал, но не нашёл подробного описания как это можно реализовать. С чего мне начать, в какую сторону рыть ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начать нужно со знакомства с [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk). Google предоставляет [клиентские библиотеки](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/downloads) для работы с Google Drive, в том числе и для Java. С Яндекс Диском мне работать не приходилось, но думаю, там дело обстоит точно так же. Во всяком случае, для работы с Microsoft OneDrive и Dropbox все очень похоже, так что Яндекс вряд ли придумал что-то особенное.